# Cascading DropDownList / TreeView data picker for 2sxc module

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

Is is posible to implement something like cascading dropdown in data edit: 
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist

Or treeview dropdown like page picker but with custom data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest versions it's not built in yet. This is a lower priority wish because a good generic solution needs quite a lot of planning.

BUT you can create your own. It's not as easy as everything else, but it's fairly standard / straight forward. Basically you have to create various angular-formly field templates and register them in 2sxc, then make sure that they "talk" to each other (or that the filtered one get's filter-values from the other).

Such a non-generic approach would be fairly simple, but you should still plan 4-6h of work if this is the first time you're doing something like this.

I recommend that you use the fibonacci-input as an example to get started - http://2sxc.org/en/Blog/post/custom-input-type-advanced-dynamic-data

Comment: OK. I will post sample if I can make it, but for now, this is OK answer.